# MS Excel: Difference between 2 columns.?

Tags: excel, ms-office

I've two columns `A` and `B` that contain lists of usernames, 
column `B` has some usernames not in column `A` How can I find them and store them in column `C`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula for cell C1:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$5,0)),B1,"")
```

Drag it down to the last row of the list in column B.

Comment: game me error Returns the logical value TRUE if value refers to any error value, such as #N/A, #VALUE!, #REF!, #DIV/0!, #NUM!, #NAME?, or #NULL!; otherwise, it returns FALSE.